When are infimal convolutions contractions?
Let $X$ be a separable Fréchet space and $\varphi,\psi:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a lower semi-continuous and convex function with $\psi$ bounded below and coercive.  Consider the infimal convolution
$$
\varphi\mathbin\square \psi(x):= \operatorname*{arginf}_{x\in X} \varphi(x-y) + \psi(y)
$$
e.g. if $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ is a Banach space then one may take $\psi=\|\cdot\|_X^2$ and obtain the proximal operator as a special case.
Under what conditions is $\varphi\mathbin\square \psi$ a construction, i.e. $L<1$-Lipschitz?

What does "arginf" mean? Maybe you mean instead $$
\varphi\square \psi(x):= \inf_{y\in X} \varphi(x-y) + \psi(y)
$$ ?

Ah so, I mean a selection into the set of accumulation points of the $\epsilon$-minimizers; and I assume its non-empty.
Tbh, one can possibly consider the Banachian case with $\psi$ being its norm squared.

I changed $\displaystyle \operatorname{arginf}{x\in X}$ to $\displaystyle \operatorname*{arginf}{x\in X}$ by changing \operatorname{arginf}_{x\in X} to \operatorname*{arginf}_{x\in X}. Also, I changed $\varphi\square\psi$ to $\varphi\mathbin\square\psi$ by putting \mathbin\square where \square had been.

Thanks @MichaelHardy a lot :)

Here are just some thoughts. I think it is a matter of curvature, so let us assume that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are smooth. Then, $y(x)$ solves the optimality condition
$$
\psi'(y(x)) = \varphi'(x - y(x)).
$$
Differentiating again, we get
$$
\nabla^2\psi(y(x)) y'(x) = \nabla^2\varphi(x - y(x)) (I - y'(x))
$$
thus,
$$
y'(x)
=
\big( \nabla^2\psi(y(x)) + \nabla^2\varphi(x-y(x)))^{-1}
\nabla^2\varphi(x-y(x))
$$
and you want to bound the norm of this guy by something smaller than $1$.
This should work if $\psi$ has positive curvature and if the curvature of $\varphi$ is bounded.
